# OrientDB - How to create edge on imported data

Tags: orientdb

I understand that in a graph DB, relations are created after insertion and instead or field to field relations, they are record to record relation. If my understanding is correct, then what do I need to do when I import a million records from a CSV file and need to relate them to records in the other table?

Is it not possible to relations (edges) at design time, before insertion so that whenever a record is inserted, it has a relation already there?

My database is detailed as below.

```
create class Country extends V
create class Immigrant extends V
create class comesFrom extends E

create property Country.c_id integer
create property Country.c_name String
create property Immigrant.i_id integer
create property Immigrant.i_name String
create property Immigrant.i_country Integer
```

If I create the edges manually, it will be like this.

```
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (1, 'USA')
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (2, 'UK')
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (3,'PAK')

insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (1, 'John',1)
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (2, 'Graham',2)
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name,i_country) values (3, 'Ali',3)

create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 1) to (select from Country where c_id = 1)
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 2) to (select from Country where c_id = 2)
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 3) to (select from Country where c_id = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OrientDB ETL to do that. For more information look at this example: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Import-from-CSV-to-a-Graph.html

Comment: Thanks but the question is how to create edges during the time of import.

Comment: Tell me more about the format of your file to import.

Comment: I have a CSV file with the following fields. [id,name,country_id]. I have a class named Immigrant in OrientDB like this. [i_id,i_name,i_country]. Then I have another class by the name Country with the following fields. [c_id,c_name]. In relation, i_country in class Immigrant relates to c_id in Country class. So now what I want to do is that while I import the CSV file, its data should go in Immigrant class, but at the same time, relation should be built between i_country and c_id. I have also updated my question to describe DB structure.